# React render image from prop

Tags: image, reactjs, webpack, resources

I am trying to pass an image url to the children and then require it as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

let color = require('../../css/colors.js');

let defaultStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexBasis: 'calc(50% - 40px)',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    margin: '20px',
    backgroundColor: color.blueCard
}

class Card extends Component {

    render() {
        const imgUrl = require(this.props.background);
        return (<div style={{
                ...defaultStyle
            }}>
            <img src={imgUrl} alt="img"/>
        </div>);
    }
}
export default Card;
```

`this.props.background` looks something like this: `"../../img/album1.jpg"`

When im starting the React App i get the following error message on `const imgUrl = require(this.props.background);`:

```
Error: Cannot find module "."
webpackMissingModule
```

The React App was created using `create-react-app`. My guess is that webpack cant parse the resource file.

Answer (score 2):

```html
    **Parent Component**

    <InputSection ref="inputS" ImD={this.getData} imageUri={require(this.state.imageurl)} />

    **Child Component**

    <img  ref="image" src={this.props.imageUri} />
```

try this, I think it will work.

Comment: Still throws `Error: cannot find module "."`

Answer (score 0):

Does not need the `require` in this case, You can simply get the `props` which you're passing from the Parent component.

for ex :

```
<Card background={your_value}/>
```

then in `Card` component

```
const imgUrl = this.props.background;
```

Comment: If I do not use `require` the right url is passed but the image isn't loaded